# Regarding Mercurial Security + recursive checkins of subrepositories

Tags: mercurial, subrepos

this is going to be a long post...sorry upfront.

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to hold together "Repositories for each project branch", and what the impact of that would be on a team.

Right now, it appears that

- Can recursively checkin code of
  nested checkins although hg status
  doesn't give much info on file
  changes within nested repos
- It
  appears that I -- and every team
  member who wants to work on the same
  project -- has to hand edit their
  subrepositoies' `.hgrc` files in order
  to make the checkin as painless and
  automated as possible.
- Can
  recursively checkin, but recursively
  checkout is not supported.

Is that a correct analysis of Hg's capabilities?

I'm really hoping not, as that's a *lot* more stick-shift coding (ie command prompt fiddling all over the place), than the average dev team I've seen could handle, while remaining productive. As I've understood it, refactoring a single assembly would probably grind the team to a halt as they stop to edit the `.hgrc` files to add location, user and password. No?

And I really want to double check that Hg can't recursively pull? Sounds like such an omission, that I feel I must have missed something.

Thanks!

PS: 
For the brave or foolish, (and in case it helps), the notes I've been keeping as I work around the problem of projects that reference library modules that reference other library modules, is as follows (note the ???? QUESTIONS??? interspersed in them...

```
MERCURIAL 

# requires an .hgsub with a ref to either
# an Hg Repo for only one Bin...?
# a website download...is that possible?
# an svn repo that allow referencing just one folder in it
# eg: "BIN/A3rdParty = svn:^/BinCache/A3rdParty/bin"


LibA\
     hg\
        .hgrc 
        # ??? QUESTION ???
        # does each user have to edit their own files by hand 
        # to allow automatic push/pull?
        # "default = https://user:pwd@bitbucket.org/xact/liba"
        # "default-push = https://user:pwd@bitbucket.org/xact/liba"
     .hgsub
     # Map of nested repos as follows:
     # "BIN/A3rdParty = svn:^/BinCache/A3rdParty/bin"
     # "EXT/LibA = https://bitbucket.org/xact/liba"
     # "EXT/LibB = https://bitbucket.org/xact/libb"
     LibA.sln
     BIN\
         [A3rdParty\SomeLib.dll]
     EXT\
     SRC\
         LibA\LibA.csproj
         # ...which References "..\..\BIN\A3rdParty\SomeLib.dll"
         LibA.Tests\LibA.Tests.csproj
         # ...which References "..\LibA\LibA.csproj"


LibB\
     hg\
        .hgrc 
        # ??? QUESTION ???
        # does each user have to edit their own files by hand 
        # to allow automatic push/pull?
        # "default = https://user:pwd@bitbucket.org/xact/libb"
        # "default-push = https://user:pwd@bitbucket.org/xact/libb"
     .hgsub
     # that contains:
     # "BIN/A3rdParty = svn:^/BinCache/A3rdParty/bin"
     # "EXT/LibA = https://bitbucket.org/xact/liba"
     # ??? QUESTION ???
     # do end users add user/pwd info here? or in the 
     # nested repos .hgrc file?
     LibB.sln
     BIN\
         [A3rdParty\SomeLib.dll]
     EXT\
         LibA\
              hg\
                .hgrc 
                # ??? QUESTION ???
                # does each user have to edit their own files by hand 
                # to allow automatic push/pull?
                # "default = https://user:pwd@bitbucket.org/xact/liba"
                # "default-push = https://user:pwd@bitbucket.org/xact/liba"
              LibA.csproj
              # ...which References "..\..\BIN\A3rdParty\SomeLib.dll"
              LibA.Tests\LibA.Tests.csproj
              # ...which References "..\LibA\LibA.csproj"
     SRC\
         LibB\LibB.csproj
         # ...which References "..\..\EXT\LibA\LibA.csproj"
         LibB.Tests\LibB.Tests.csproj
         # ...which References "..\LibB\LibB.csproj"


ProjA\
      hg\
        .hgrc 
        # ??? QUESTION ???
        # does each user have to edit their own files by hand 
        # to allow automatic push/pull?
        # "default = https://user:pwd@bitbucket.org/xact/proja"
        # "default-push = https://user:pwd@bitbucket.org/xact/proja"
      .hgsub
      # that contains:
      # "BIN/A3rdParty = svn:^/BinCache/A3rdParty/bin"
      # "EXT/LibA = https://bitbucket.org/xact/liba"
      # "EXT/LibB = https://bitbucket.org/xact/libb"
      # ??? QUESTION ???
      # do end users add user/pwd info here? or in the 
      # nested repos .hgrc file?
      BIN\
          [A3rdParty\SomeLib.dll]
      EXT\
          LibA\
               hg\
                .hgrc 
                # ??? QUESTION ???
                # does each user have to edit their own files by hand 
                # to allow automatic push/pull?
                # "default = https://user:pwd@bitbucket.org/xact/liba"
                # "default-push = https://user:pwd@bitbucket.org/xact/liba"
               LibA.csproj
               # ...which References "..\..\BIN\A3rdParty\SomeLib.dll"
               LibA.Tests\LibA.Tests.csproj
               # ...which References "..\LibA\LibA.csproj"
          LibB\
               hg\
                .hgrc 
                # ??? QUESTION ???
                # does each user have to edit their own files by hand 
                # to allow automatic push/pull?
                # "default = https://user:pwd@bitbucket.org/xact/libb"
                # "default-push = https://user:pwd@bitbucket.org/xact/libb"
               LibB\LibB.csproj
          # ...which References "..\..\EXT\LibA\LibA.csproj"
          # Important: note that it is same path offset
          # as when within context of LibB.sln
          LibB.Tests\LibB.Tests.csproj
          # ...which References "..\LibB\LibB.csproj"
      SRC\
          ProjA\ProjA.csproj
          ProjA.Tests\ProjA.Tests.csproj
```

Comment: What do you mean by "recursively checkout"?

Comment: You can store your credentials once on the system, but unless you install the keyring extension and get that working, the password will be in cleartext. If that's OK, let me know and I'll show you how to do it it. This would remove any need for editing of the hgrc files in the repositories just to add authentication.

Comment: This sounds like something you should *discuss* with us at mercurial@selenic.com instead of putting it here. StackOverflow is not the right way to reach the Mercurial community.

Comment: @Lasse:**Recursive**
By recursive, meant working with the subrepos from only working on the root repo, using HgTortoise (once setup) for everything it all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer some of your questions though I really think you should discuss this with us instead of doing a Q&A here.

> Right now, it appears that
>
> - Can recursively checkin code of nested checkins although hg status doesn't give much info on file changes within nested repos

See `hg status --subrepos` or `hg status -S` for short.

> - It appears that I -- and every team member who wants to work on the same project -- has to hand edit their subrepositoies' `.hgrc` files in order to make the checkin as painless and automated as possible.

No need to put usernamed and passwords into the `.hg/hgrc` files -- you should instead configure [caching of HTTP credentials in Mercurial](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/remote/#caching-of-http-s-credentials).

> - Can recursively checkin, but recursively checkout is not supported.

Checkout, i.e., update, is recursive. When you do `hg clone` to get a local repository, then Mercurial will notice the `.hgsub` and `.hgsubstate` files and it will recursively clone the subrepositories referenced there.

> And I really want to double check that Hg can't recursively pull? Sounds like such an ommission, that I feel I must have missed something.

Yes, you're missing how Mercurial knows which subrepositories you want. Please see the documentation [on the wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Pull) or [the Kick Start guide](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/#pushing-and-pulling).

Comment: Editing the hgrc files, probably to add authentication, to avoid having to type in username/password X times on every push.

Comment: Thanks Lasse, I just read the big blog of notes at the end of the question and that made me reach the same conclusion.

Comment: @Martin:Thanks for your response.

**Regarding hg status -S**
Found command switch last night. Great: can now see what I am doing in subrepos.

Comment: @Martin: **Regarding keyring extension**
Also came across this last night. Found instructions for linux (am on Windows) as well as mention that I have it already installed via HgTortoise. But no instructions in HgTortoise on how to use *it*...Still trying to figure that out.

Comment: @Lasse @Martin: **Security**
Yes was editing .hgrc for that reason. Still trying to figure out why there is difference between user:pwd in paths, or separate in [auth]
section. HgTortoise seems to write them directly to path. 
Does it use paths, and fall back to [auth] if no user:pwd specified?
If so, could I use [auth] section in my global settings, if I don't figure out keyring?

Comment: @Lasse: **StackOverflow**
Didn't think of using the Hg community first... StackOverflow has proven to be so useful and fast for most subjects, over time... For future question threads, I try the community first, ok?

Comment: @Lasse:**Recursive**
By recursive, meant working with the subrepos from only working on the root repo, using HgTortoise (once setup) for everything it all possible.

Comment: @Lasse, @Martin: if I host Parent and Child Repos on bitbucket, and checkin to Parent an .hgsub that has
Child = https://bitbucket.org/user/child
When a team member checks out Parent, Hg will (assuming parent+child auth is set up) check out Parent **and** Child in one go, **and** mark in Child and Parent repo's .hgrc [paths] the default and default-push values of bitbucket, so that if parent is pushed, child will be pushed too? And subsequent pull's will work too?
If that automatic -- recursive pull and push of projects from parent -- then things are looking much better than yesterday :-)

Comment: When you clone a repository with sub-repos, mercurial will make local clones of those sub-repos, and then pull on demand into them. By "on demand" I mean that if the parent repo reference revision no 7 in a sub-repo, and the central clone of that repo has more than 7 revisions, Mercurial will clone and pull those 7 revisions. Only if you later update your parent repo to a new revision that references a newer revision in the sub-repo will Mercurial pull down to get that new revision, before updating to it.

Comment: @Lasse: But if I just reference the tip (no specific revision number) it will continue to pull, right? And if it does all that... And if does all this.

Comment: @Lasse: if it can do all this...why does http://bit.ly/fA4zQm say "Mercurial will always attempt to first push all subrepository of a repository before pushing the current repository, thereby ensuring that the repository being pushed to, cannot end up with referring to an inexistent version of a subrepository. Pulling is on the other hand not recursive, because Mercurial cannot know which subrepositories to pull before updating to a specific changeset has been done."

Comment: @Lasse: on one hand the docs say that push is recursive, but pull isn't...and I think that you and @Martin have both answered that if cloned (so that .hgrc is automatically edited to show where it came from) both push and pull **are** recursive. Is that correct?

Comment: What happens when you pull into the master repo is that no, the sub-repos aren´t pulled at the same time. However, when you updat the master repo to a new revision, and that new revision is referencing a newer revision in a sub-repo than that sub-repo currently has locally, that sub-repo will be pulled, and then updated.

Comment: Example. Master repo at revision 10 (local tip) references sub-repo revision 17. When you cloned that master repo, the sub-repo was pulled to revision 17, and updated to revision 17. Later you pull into the master repo, the sub-repo is not pulled. However, when you update the master repo to revision 13, and revision 13 of the master repo references revision 21 of the sub-repo, which the local clone of that repo doesn´t have (yet), that sub-repo is then pulled to revision 21, and then updated. You should make some test repositories and test this.